# How can we show that it is the local maximum?

Tags: calculus

I want to find the local maxima of $f(x,y,z)=-(x+y+z)$, when

$$x^2+y=3, x+3y+2z=7.$$

I found that the local extremum is $(x,y,z)=\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{11}{4},-\frac{3}{8} \right)$.

How can we show that $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{11}{4},-\frac{3}{8} \right)$ is the local maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize the constraints with $(t, 3-t^2, 0.5(3t^2-t-2))$, then $f(x,y,z) = -0.5t^2-0.5t-2 = -0.5(t+0.5)^2 - 1.75$.

Maximum occurs at $t = -0.5$, where $x = -0.5$, $y = 3-t^2 = 2.75$, $z = 0.5(3t^2-t-2) = -0.375$ as required.

No calculus needed.

Answer (score 1):

take the first constraint and subtract the second and rearenge you find

$$
   -2(x+y+z) = -4 -x^2 - x \leq -4 - (\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{2}
$$ with $x=-1/2$ plug this into the constraints and you get your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate $y,z$ from the constraints, with

$$y=3-x^2, z=\frac{7-x-3y}2=\frac{3x^2-x-2}2$$

and optimize

$$-(x+y+z)=-\frac{x^2+x+4}2.$$